# How could I save special characters on text type on Joomla xml config file?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Hi eveyone I have to save an Api key on the xml configuration file for a Joomla plugin, the value of the Api key includes a logical or symbol,so when I press the save button the text field value is not saved

```
`<field name="apilive" size="75" type="text" label="Api live" description="Api Key Live" filter="raw"/>`
```

This is an example of the value in the texfield

[image: textfiel wiht example value]

If I erase the logical or symbol it works as it should, could someone tell me wish type of field should I use instead or how to save this value in this kind of cases?

Comment: Pleas ask all of your Joomla questions [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.